# Pick $\alpha$ such that the spectral radius is minimized

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A: \mathbb{C^n} \to \mathbb{C^n}$ has only positive real eigenvalues. Show how to choose $\alpha$ such that the spectral radius of $I-\alpha A$ will be the smallest.

Any hints or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\lambda_{max}$ and $\lambda_{min}$ be the largest and smallest eigenvalues of $A$ (respectively).  The eigenvalues of $I - \alpha A$ will lie on the line segment in $\Bbb C$ that connects $1 - \alpha \lambda_{min}$ to $1 - \alpha \lambda_{max}$.  In particular, they lie on the line $\{1 - \alpha t \mid t \in \Bbb R\}$.

**Solution:** Select an $\alpha > 0$ such that $1 - \alpha \lambda_{min} = -(1 - \alpha \lambda_{max})$